# MvvmCross-SecureStorage in PCL

Tags: c#, plugins, mono, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to add MvvmCross-SecureStorage plugin of MvvmCross to PCL wich contains classes shared between Universal Widows app iOs apps and Android apps, but I'm getting this kind of error.

> Could not install package 'Beezy.MvvmCross.Plugins.SecureStorage 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Anybody successfully added this plugin to PCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/ChristianRuiz/MvvmCross-SecureStorage it looks like this project doesn't yet support the new unified `xamarinios10` target which is included in your list.

One route forwards would be to add unified support to that open source project and to send them a Pull Request.

Comment: I've tried to find exactly this information to check the supported projects. Where did you found it?

Comment: Sure - there is a guide for changing MonoTouch to Xamarin.iOS on http://kerry.lothrop.de/unified-api-for-xamarin-ios/

Comment: Ok, I have created the pull request, hopefully original creator will pull the changes.

Thanks man